# C# admin rights issues

Tags: c#

I trying to make a program which connect to a game ("quick connect").

When i start the application as an administrator and connect to the game, it have weird issues (e.g. shortkeys doesn't respond for the ingame keys and the game doesn't load some model files), but when i start without admin rights it works fine, however i need the admin rights for other purposes (file operations).

I tried to rerun the program with the runas commandline command, the app had no admin rights, but the game still doesn't work right.

```
// OnClick event
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c runas /trustlevel:0x20000 \"myapp.exe rerun\"");
proc.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(proc);

// Program.cs
if(!admin && args[0].Equals("rerun"))
{
    ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c game.exe ipAndPortToConnect");
    proc.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
    proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process.Start(proc);
}
```

I tried many combinations but none of them worked.

I can't figure out what the hell causing it...

Comment: What are the weird issues?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write. Shortkeys doesn't respond for the ingame keys and the game doesn't load some model files.

Comment: What OS are you running this under?  Windows 7 and Windows 8 might require app signing for certain features.

Comment: You are setting the process's WorkingDirectory to your launcher's StartupPath. Is this intended ? Is your launcher indeed in the same directory as the game executable ?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I run windows 7.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme Yes, the program in same directory as the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the Task Manager, you'll see the game still runs as a different user, namely Administrator. This most likely means the game saves some information in the user profile, for example under AppSettings (like hotkeys in configuration files), or game modifications that are stored in AppData, which could cause the issues you mentioned.

The user who 'reruns' your program is still the elevated user, albeit with less permissions, and that user launches the game. You cannot "unimpersonate" a process properly to the point the OS thinks it runs as the logged in user, so you'll have to do something else.

You can either see if you can move the user-specific resources to a path relative to the game, not the user, or start the process by any other means but directly from yours, for example using a Scheduled Task.

But why didn't you update your [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286539/start-process-from-c-sharp)?

Comment: Oh i see, and how is it possible to change the process owner to the user?